# assign parameter from other function to a variable

Tags: shell

in main function, i called and passed 2 parameters to function cleanexpiredfiles, function cleanexpiredfiles add more characters to parameter 2 and then pass to function deleteFiles, now the problem is: in function deleteFiles, $2 return correct result, but if i use deleteFolder=$2, then $deleteFolder return nothing,

echo $2 return correct result
echo $deleteFolder return nothing

```
function deleteFiles
{
 expireTime=$1
 deleteFolder=$2

 echo $deleteFolder
}

function cleanexpiredfiles
{
 for fileelement in `ls $2`
 do
  deleteFiles $1 $2"/"$fileelement
 done
 }

 function main()
 {
  cleanexpiredfiles $((16*60*60)) /opt/gdsmigration/logs
 }

 main $@
```

echo $2 or echo $deleteFiles should return the same result,

Comment: What do you think `echo $deleteFiles` does?

Comment: sorry, it is actually echo $deleteFolder,

Comment: Running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ would be a place to start.

Comment: Some notes: (1) See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: `function` syntax; that's a legacy ksh-ism that wasn't incorporated into the POSIX standard; better to use the standardized syntax `deleteFiles() { ...`; (2) Quotes matter. `deleteFiles "$1" "$2/$fileelement"` is much more correct (won't split your variables on spaces). (3) Don't **ever** use `ls` in scripts, unless their output is used for no purpose other than end-user display; see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: (4) Always declare your locals; unless you run `local expireTime deleteFolder`, the variables you set remain set even after the function finishes. (5) Note that quotes matter even just for `echo`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). And unless you quote the `"$@"` in `main "$@"`, it behaves identically to (read: with all the same bugs as) unquoted `$*`.

Comment: A correct version of your loop might look like `for fileElement in "$2"/*; do deleteFiles "$1" "$fileElement"; done` -- the glob output will include the directory name already, so it doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: after i change `ls $2` to "$2"/*, it works fine, thanks,

Comment: That's the power of @CharlesDuffy...